# Issue while loading Bitmap in AsyncTack

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am succesfully parsed xml and got text and url from tags and attributes.
Text I was succesfully set into my ListView, but I cannot load my bitmap Into ImageView. I think I am forgetting something small, like some conversion somewhere or I have wrote wrong AsyncTask.

**Here Is my parsing and AsyncTask call:**

```
    private List<SomeItem> items = new ArrayList();

listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        IV = findViewById(R.id.iconsrc);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.myxml);

            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (parser.getEventType()){

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(iconsrc)){
                            iconsrcVALUE = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                            myBitmap = new AsyncForBitmap().execute(iconsrcVALUE).get();
                            IV.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }

                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT :
                        tagtext = parser.getText();
                         break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(displayname)) {

                            programmes.add(new SomeItem(tagtext, myBitmap));
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Error while loading xml document: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**My AsyncTask:**

```
class AsyncForBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private Exception exception;

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url=new URL(urls[0]);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent());
                return bitmap;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

**Maybe I must add(overwrite) onPostExecute() method? But what I need to do there?**

I tried smth like:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

But It Is wrong.

Comment: Why unvoting? If this problem was solved earlier on stackoverflow, pls give me a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like passing of ImageView into AsyncTask in constructor. For this first modify your AsyncTask as below:

```
class AsyncForBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final ImageView mImageView;

    public AsyncForBitmap(ImageView imageView){
        mImageView = imageView;
    }

    private Exception exception;

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL(urls[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent());
            return bitmap;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

And then, simply do as:

```
 ...
 case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
     if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(iconsrc)){
        iconsrcVALUE = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
        new AsyncForBitmap(IV).execute(iconsrcVALUE);
     }
     break;
```

Comment: just was trying this and getting: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference` on this string `mimageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
`

Comment: oh, I understand this problem, I am doing `myBitmap = new AsyncForBitmap(IV).execute(iconsrcVALUE).get();` instead of your `new AsyncForBitmap(IV).execute(iconsrcVALUE)`, because I need done `items.add(new SomeItem(tagtext, myBitmap));` in my `case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:`

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk Looks like imageView that is being passed in AsyncTask constructor parameter is null. Check if that view is properly initialized.

Comment: and here `myBitmap` is null.

Comment: So why I cannot do `myBitmap = new AsyncForBitmap(IV).execute(iconsrcVALUE).get();` for using myBitmap variable in `programmes.add(new SomeItem(tagtext, myBitmap));` ?

Comment: according to debugger variable myBitmap is not NULL. I am having null object reference only on  `mimageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: In `doInBackground()` returns null, maybe it should returns something other?

Comment: I think I am close to solving this problem but still missing some important detail.

Comment: And my imageView that is passed in AsyncTask is not null - `IV = findViewById(R.id.iconsrc);` I have done this before parsing in `onCreate()`

Comment: No, I have NULL in IV:) I forgot, that iconsrc in other resource, so here is the only problem. Thank you, @Chintan Soni.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: getting same `null object reference`, please check my comments to user Chintan Soni

Comment: why I cannot do myBitmap = new AsyncForBitmap(IV).execute(iconsrcVALUE).get(); for using myBitmap variable In programmes.add(new SomeItem(tagtext, myBitmap)); ?